# Switching to a different user from a shell script

Tags: shell, ubuntu-14.04

There are a number of solutions on stackoverflow, but they all require using sudo, but this is not what I want to do (switching to root privileges). What I want to do is su, and pass the password to it (there will be no security issues, as I will be asking the user for a user name and password), let's call them $user_name and $user_passwd.

I tried:

```
echo $user_passwd | su $user_name
```

But it did not work.

How do I do this from a shell script without having to switch to use sudo?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/. Use runuser command.

Comment: If you switch this to an answer, I will give you credit for it

Comment: The answer can be in the link, for a more specific answer, try a more specific question. What do you wish to accomplish with that? The script will run with root account and only one command with another user? Can you post a piece of your script?